# Absolutely convergence property on normed spaces implying continuity of linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a linear operator. Suppose $f$ is such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x_n)$ is convergent in $Y$ whenever $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|x_n\| < \infty$.

With this hypothesis, we can prove that $f$ is continuous. Below is what I tried so far.

Because $f$ is linear, we just have to show that $f$ is continuous at $0$. The series hypothesis makes me want to use some argument with sequences. The first idea is to take an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ such that $x_n\to 0$ and show that $f(x_n)\to f(0) = 0$. Therefore $f$ is continuous at $0$ and the problem is solved.

Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>n_0 \implies \|x_n - 0\| = \|x_n\| < \varepsilon$. Yet, it's not guaranteed that we have $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\|x_{n_i}\|<\infty$, but we can take some subsequence $(x_{n_i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\|x_{n_i}\|<1/2^i$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Then we have $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\|x_{n_i}\|<1$, therefore $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_{n_i})$ is convergent in $Y$. So we can conclude that the argument works for all subsequences of $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ going fast enough to $0$.

I don't think this is enough to prove continuity at $0$, it should be for the entire sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, not just some subsequences. How can I improve this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please explain why the negative vote. I wrote the question properly and showed effort to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $X$, tending to zero, but $y_n=f(x_n)$ does not converge to zero in $Y$. So we must have $\alpha=\limsup_{n\to\infty}||y_n||>0$. There exists a subsequence $y_{n_i}$ such that $\lim_{i\to\infty}||f(x_{n_i})||=||y_{n_i}||=\alpha>0$.
On the other hand, applying your argument we can find yet another subsequence of the $x_{n_i}$, say, $x_{n_{i_j}}$, such that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}||x_{n_{i_j}}|| <\infty$. But the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f(x_{n_{i_j}})$ does not converge, because the general term does not tend to zero, indeed, the norms tend to $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Where the linearity of $f$ is used?

Comment: @Integral It is not used, and not needed. In fact, the following statement holds: Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map. Assume that whenever $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||x_n||$ is convergent, the sequence $f(x_n)$ tends to zero in $Y$. Then $f$ is continuous.